How to handle SSL_ERROR_SSL on SSL_accept
I'm using OpenSSL (the development library, <openssl/ssl.h>) to program a small, simple server in C.
Since I'm only testing it locally, I use a self-signed certificate. When first connecting, since my browser doesn't trust the certificate, SSL_accept() returns SSL_ERROR_SSL, which is fine, that's what should happen.
I'm wondering how I should handle the SSL_ERROR_SSL error, since the docs on SSL_get_error() say:

SSL_ERROR_SSL
A non-recoverable, fatal error in the SSL library occurred, usually a protocol error. The OpenSSL error queue contains more information on the error. If this error occurs then no further I/O operations should be performed on the connection and SSL_shutdown() must not be called.

If I can't can SSL_shutdown(), what should I do with the SSL connection? How do I reuse the SSL* object? And why can't I call SSL_shutdown()?
I tried looking at the error queue, which gave me the expected error of untrusted certificate. The OpenSSL site doesn't have any answers, and it seems that most programs try to avoid handling this problem instead of dealing with it.

There is no SSL connection. There is an accepted plaintext socket which must be closed.


If I can't can SSL_shutdown(), what should I do with the SSL connection? How do I reuse the SSL* object? And why can't I call SSL_shutdown()?

You can't use SSL_shutdown() in this case because it is a non-recoverable, fatal error. The SSL session failed to be established, and the state of the socket is unknown. So there is nothing you can reliably shut down. And, the SSL object cannot be reused.
So, the only thing you can do is destroy the SSL object, close the socket, and move on.

In the event that an untrusted certificate is encountered, SSL_accept() returning SSL_ERROR_SSL signals an irreversible, catastrophic problem in the SSL library, usually a protocol error.
You shouldn't invoke SSL_shutdown() in this scenario, nor should you carry out any more I/O activities on the connection.
You can take the following actions to resolve this problem and carry on utilising the SSL* object:
To tidy up the SSL object, execute SSL_free(ssl) to release the allocated resources linked to the SSL object. The SSL session and all related data structures will be released as a result.
Close the underlying socket: To free up system resources, close the socket descriptor connected to the SSL connection. For this, you can utilise the shutdown() or close() functions.
Respond to the mistake politely.

This answer reads like an AI generated it, which is not allowed on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gen-ai-policy
